# Не могу сделать компиляцию в android в Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, gradle

При компиляции андроид у меня произошла такая ошибка

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.16f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.16f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
USERDOMAIN = USER-80U3IB4NR3
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
TMP = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = a503
OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\User\OneDrive
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_20948_YONBEIVIKPZNXUQE
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\User
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.16f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.16f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
USERNAME = User
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22
TEMP = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\User\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
COMPUTERNAME = USER-80U3IB4NR3
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemDrive = C:
windir = C:\Windows
HOMEPATH = \Users\User
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming
OneDrive = C:\Users\User\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
SESSIONNAME = Console
LOGONSERVER = \\USER-80U3IB4NR3
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local
HOMEDRIVE = C:
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = USER-80U3IB4NR3
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\игры мои\burger\burger_king_govno\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']
   > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 743ms
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Помогите пожалуйста!
Вот картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужен перевод этого сообщения? `Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details.`

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чём дело. Нужно чтобы на пути к проекту не было кириллицы